# How to use fread or read_delim in R on characters with no linebreak

Tags: r, fread, readr

I have several .txt files which need to be imported to R as dataframes for some data analysis. One of these files has no EOL in any form, so I'm left wondering how I would go about to import that.

```
\"A\";\"B\";\"C\";\"D\";\"D\";\"E\";\"F\";\"G\";\"H\";\"I\";\"J\";\"K\";\"L\";\"M\";\"N\";\"O\";\"P\";\"Q\";\"R\";\"S\";\"T\";\"U\";\"V\"\"1\";4;\"55-555-5555-555\";1234-56-78;\"111\";1510;5;1234-12-17;12345.1234512345;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA\"2\";6;\"22-222-2222-222\";5678-56-78;\"222\";2051;0;NA;0;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA
```

This is how the first ~500 characters of that .txt file look like. The EOL would need to be placed like this:

```
\"A\";\"B\";\"C\";\"D\";\"D\";\"E\";\"F\";\"G\";\"H\";\"I\";\"J\";\"K\";\"L\";\"M\";\"N\";\"O\";\"P\";\"Q\";\"R\";\"S\";\"T\";\"U\";\"V\"

\"1\";4;\"55-555-5555-555\";1234-56-78;\"111\";1510;5;1234-12-17;12345.1234512345;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA

\"2\";6;\"22-222-2222-222\";5678-56-78;\"222\";2051;0;NA;0;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA
```

Normally I would just gsub a "\n" to the places I need it to be, but there is no reoccurring string at the places where I would place a \n, so I don't think that gsub would work in this instance.

Seeing how the missing values are clearly indicated with NA, is there a function similar to read_delim that has a "col_number = x" argument? Like the first x values are the headers, the next x values are the values of the first row and so on and so forth?

If it changes anything, these .txt files are rather big (>300mb).

Big thank you to Julian_Hn. Works like a charm.

Comment: Is number of columns in each line fixed?
You know this number?

Comment: Yes and yes. But I dont know the number of rows.

Comment: see answer by Julian_Hn, put number of columns in ncol and omit nrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just read this in as a vector and then reformat as matrix with the number of columns you know are in the dataset. This essentially does what you want

```
str <- "\"A\";\"B\";\"C\";\"D\";\"D\";\"E\";\"F\";\"G\";\"H\";\"I\";\"J\";\"K\";\"L\";\"M\";\"N\";\"O\";\"P\";\"Q\";\"R\";\"S\";\"T\";\"U\";\"V\";\"1\";4;\"55-555-5555-555\";1234-56-78;\"111\";1510;5;1234-12-17;12345.1234512345;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;\"2\";6;\"22-222-2222-222\";5678-56-78;\"222\";2051;0;NA;0;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA"

vec <- strsplit(str,";")[[1]]
//EDIT: add byrow = T To stay in the right format. Thanks Yuriy
table <- matrix(vec,ncol=23,nrow=3, byrow = T)
df <- as.data.frame(table)
```

Comment: Good answer.
I think adding byrow = TRUE in `table <- matrix(vec,ncol=23,nrow=3, byrow = TRUE)` can make it closer needed output.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good start. Just need to find out how many rows there are. //EDIT: Actually finding out how many rows there are shouldnt be too hard. I could just count the ";" and then divide that by the number of columns.

Comment: just divide the length of the char-vector by the number of columns. That should give you the number of rows you need.